# Using Service Account with Dataflow - Getting storage.objects.get access error

Tags: java, storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a Dataflow job from project **A** to project **B**.

I can execute the job in project B without problem but when I try to read an input file from the storage in project A the job failed with "xxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to gs://xxxx-bucket"

This is weird because I'm setting the service account credentials in the Dataflow job Options like this:

```java
Set<String> scopeList = new HashSet<String>();
scopeList.addAll(DataflowScopes.all());

PipelineOptionsFactory.register(CustomOptions.class);
CustomOptions customOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
                                                            .withValidation()
                                                            .as(CustomOptions.class);


customOptions.setGcpCredential(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(credentialContent.getBytes())).createScoped(scopeList));
```

It looks like the code before is not doing anything because the credentials shown in the error is a Compute Service Account and not the same that I'm setting in the Pipeline Options.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

The permission for the Service Account inside the Dataflow Code are:

- Dataflow Admin
- Dataflow Worker
- Service Account User
- Storage Admin

All of these permissions are in the project B. That's why I can execute a dataflow job from project A to project B without a problem.

Comment: Which project does the gs://xxxx-bucket belong to? If it belongs to project A, and the service account for project B is trying to access it, then there will be a permission error. Here are some links on access control in GCS.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may work, please let me know if it does not.

Which project does the gs://xxxx-bucket belong to? If it belongs to project A, and the service account for project B is trying to access it, then there will be a permission error.

Please browse to the bucket in the owner project, using the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and give the service account permissions.

- Use the menu in the top left to select "Storage"
- Locate the bucket
- Select "...",
- Then "Edit bucket permissions"
- "Add Members"
- Add the service account which you wish to add permissions for.

Answer (score 1):

Within the project A, in the bucket you are requesting the file, you should add the service account (From project B) to the bucket and grant the permissions to read ().

By default, dataflow uses the GCE service account, this is the account which writes/reads on the buckets, also it is the account which access to other Google Cloud APIs.

Here are some [examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-iam) about how to add members to your buckets and the permissions by [role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) available in Cloud storage